# Trouble with setting a reference int

Tags: c#, checkbox, ref

I have a page with a listing of products in a table (which is built with divs but I digress), and one column is called "Add to Shopping List" and contains a checkbox. If that checkbox is checked, then the product for that row should be placed into the user's order. On submission, the user is taken to an order review page with all the items they had selected.

The problem right now is that, even though I set the quantity of a product to "1" when the checkbox is selected, every time the form is submitted, the number of items selected for ordering is always 0.

The function that is meant to see if any items have been selected for ordering upon submission is called checkQtys:

```
protected bool checkQtys(ref int ItemCnt, ref ArrayList LinesToOrder)
{
    Repeater locationRepeater = (Repeater)FindControl("locationRepeater");

    bool validQtys = true;
    string productID = "";
    int qty;
    qtyErrorMsg.Text = "";
    qtyErrorMsgTop.Text = "";
    foreach (RepeaterItem repItem in locationRepeater.Items)
    {
        if (repItem != null)
        {
            Repeater areaRepeater = (Repeater)repItem.FindControl("areaRepeater");
            if (areaRepeater != null)
            {
                foreach (RepeaterItem skuItm in areaRepeater.Items)
                {

                    if (skuItm != null)
                    {
                        Label SkuID = (Label)skuItm.FindControl("SkuID");
                        Label qtyID = (Label)skuItm.FindControl("qtyID");

                        PlaceHolder inner = (PlaceHolder)skuItm.FindControl("ProductTable");

                        if (inner != null)
                        {
                            foreach (Control ct in inner.Controls)
                            {
                                if (ct is CheckBox)
                                {
                                    CheckBox lineQty = (CheckBox)ct;
                                    Label prodID = (Label)inner.FindControl("productID");
                                    if (lineQty.Checked)
                                    {

                                        productID = prodID.Text;
                                        qty = 1;
                                        LinesToOrder.Add(new LineItem(productID, qty));
                                        ItemCnt++;
                                        validQtys = true;
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
    return validQtys;
}
```

*Note: This original was meant to check a textbox value--the "Add To Shopping List" column was originally set to take user input for specific quantities but that has been changed to the checkbox.

This is the submit function:

```
protected void orderSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ItemCnt = 0;
    bool validQtys = true;
    ArrayList LinesToOrder = new ArrayList();
    Label lb = FindControl("order") as Label;

    if (checkQtys(ref ItemCnt, ref LinesToOrder))
    {
        string value = checkQtys(ref ItemCnt, ref LinesToOrder).ToString();
        Response.Write("value: " + value + "<br />");
        if (ItemCnt == 0)
        {//make sure at least one item with proper qty amount is entered before submitting the order
            validQtys = false;
            noItemMsg.Visible = true;
            noItemMsg.Text = "<br /><br />You must order at least one item<br />";
            noItemMsgTop.Visible = true;
            noItemMsgTop.Text = "You must order at least one item<br />";
        }
        if (validQtys)
        {//save the information to a session variable and send users to order review page      
            try
            {
                foreach (LineItem WorkLine in LinesToOrder)
                {
                    lb.Text += WorkLine.SKUID + ", " + WorkLine.Qty + ";";
                }

                Session["orderComplete"] = lb.Text;
            }

            catch (Exception x)
            {
                Response.Write(x.Message.ToString());
            }
            Response.Redirect("/united-states/market/office-buildings/obproductmap/OrderReview");

        }
    }
}
```

What happens in the above function is that ItemCnt is always 0, and thus the user never can go to the order review page even if they have checked at least one of the checkboxes in the product listing table. I have no clue why this is happening--with the ref int value for ItemCnt being set in checkQtys, it should not be coming in as 0 in orderSubmit unless it is actually 0.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you use `ref LinesToOrder` when (from my quick look over) you don't ever do `LinesToOrder = XXXXXXXX` anywhere in the code. Also why are you using `ArrayList`, it much preferred to use the typed versions like `List<LineItem>`. Lastly, based on your capitalization you likely came from a Java background. C# uses [different naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) than Java.

Comment: What I want to do with LinesToOrder is build each row for the order review--LinesToOrder adds a new product to be stored for the order process. I included the class code for LineItem in my question to clarify what I mean.

Comment: You still did not explain why you did `ref ArrayList LinesToOrder` instead of the `ArrayList LinesToOrder`. The class `LineItem` has nothing to do with weather you need to pass the variable as reference or not.

Comment: I used ref ArrayList LinesToOrder because I wanted to pass in the products ordered to the submit button.

Comment: But you can do that without using `ref`. If you took the `ref` off of `ArrayList` your code would not change its behavior at all. The only time you need to use `ref` is when you have a passed in parameter on the left hand side of a `=` and you want that change to show in the calling class. For example `ItemCnt++` is really `ItemCnt = ItemCnt + 1`, because `ItemCnt` is on the left hand side of a `=` you need the ref. However `LinesToOrder.Add(...` does not require a `ref` to modify the collection.

Comment: You don't need the `ref`. `ArrayList` is already a reference type. Also, `ArrayList` is obsolete and should no longer be used. If it only holds `LineItem` objects, then use `List<LineItem>` instead.

Comment: Ok, I updated my code to use List<> instead of ArrayList. But what should I do about the segment of the orderSubmit function which stores each item ordered by the customer into a label called lbl.Text? This is label's text then is set into a session variable which is passed on to the order summary page...

Comment: You should rollback your edits to the question.  Your edits make some of the comments seem meaningless!

Comment: Ok, I rolled back the changes so now the question is in the original setup...I'm still having trouble, though--I still don't know what I am supposed to do with List<LineItem> when it comes to the orderSubmit function :(